# Can you reference changelog id in liquibase script?

Tags: liquibase

Is there anyway to reference the changeLog id in your sql? We're in the middle of moving our database over to liquibase, but we already have an Environment table which has key value pairs, one of which is "database_version". I want all our liquibase changes to also update the value for the "database_version"  with the change_log id.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in, but the extension system (http://liquibase.org/extensions) will allow you to implement it yourself.

The easiest approach would probably be to add a liquibase.changelog.visitor.ChangeExecListener implementation updates your table after each change is executed.

Comment: Are there any variables that can be referenced from liquibase script?

Comment: There are changlog parameters (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html) that can be set changelog-file wide, but they cannot change during the source of execution (i.e. from one changeSet to the next).  There are some built-in parameters, mainly around the database such as database.currentDateTimeFunction, database.databaseMajorVersion, database.defaultSchemaName, etc.